# Using WriteLine to prints out in file

Tags: file, f#

I used the following code, to write a `mylist` in a `*.txt` file.

```
let outFile = new StreamWriter("4.txt")
let writeNumbersInFile (numbersToupleList)=function
    |[] -> ()
    |head::tail -> outFile.WriteLine(string (head))



let mylist= [1;2;3;4]
writeNumbersInFile mylist
outFile.Close()
```

This code succesfully creates a `4.txt`, but when I open it, there is nothing there, however i expect to see

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: For a start - you have no recursion so I would expect just `1` in the file

Comment: there are two problems: first you missed the recursive call (so you will only see the first element) and second you should `outFile.Flush()` before you close it

Comment: ... also remove the `(numbersToupleList)` .... you did not tell us about the warning you get on line `writeNumbersInFile mylist` ... as it is this will do nothing ... you probably don't need `.Flush` at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should work - not how I removed the `numbersToupleList` argument - you don't need it (and you did not use it) because `function` has an implicit argument:

```
let outFile = new StreamWriter("4.txt")
let rec writeNumbersInFile =
    function
    |[] -> ()
    |head::tail -> 
        outFile.WriteLine (string head)
        writeNumbersInFile tail


let mylist= [1;2;3;4]
writeNumbersInFile mylist
outFile.Flush()
```

of course the recursion is not really needed (there are higher-order-functions to do this for you) - you can use `Seq.iter` or `List.iter` instead:

```
let outFile = new StreamWriter("4.txt")

let writeNumbersInFile =
    Seq.iter (string >> outFile.WriteLine)

let mylist= [1;2;3;4]
writeNumbersInFile mylist
outFile.Flush()
```

and now you should probably refactor this into something like this - note that I had to give the type of `file` so that F# can decide which `StreamWriter` constructor to use and that this will dispose the `StreamWriter` as soon as the work is done in `writeNumbersInFile` (the `use`) - so you will not keep file-handles around till the GC kicks in:

```
let writeNumbersInFile (file : string) (numbers : int seq) =
    use outFile = new StreamWriter (file)
    Seq.iter (string >> outFile.WriteLine) numbers
    outFile.Flush ()

[1;2;3;4]
|> writeNumbersInFile "4.txt"
```

Comment: I have an error: ' The type 'int list' is not compatible with the type 'seq<obj>''

Comment: where? - I checked the 2nd and 3rd version locally and it did work

Comment: I used the third version, in line i call the function
**[1;2;3;4] |> writeNumbersInFile "4.txt"**

Comment: this works on my system as is - what F# version are you using? Anyway I'll add the type can you check if it works if you replace `lines` with `(lines : int seq)`?

Comment: Ok this happens if you commit it step by step to F# interactive - sorry for this (I did sent the complete block at once and so F# will infer the correct types - same is true if you use it in a .fs file)